# Multiple sets of input data for Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-unit-testing

Using Visual Studio 2019. The `MSTest` unit testing framework for C# has the `DataRow` attribute which allows test methods to be automatically called with multiple sets of constant input data. For example:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(11.99, 4.55)] // One or more sets of constant input test data
[DataRow(50.00, 40.00)]
public void Debit_WithValidAmount_UpdatesBalance_WithConstantData(double balance, double debit)
{
    // ...method called twice with {11.99, 4.55} and {50.00, 40.00}
}
```

Is it possible to have multiple sets of constant test input data with Microsoft's `Native Unit Test` framework, also called the `Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++`?

`MSTest` also allows generator methods to create dynamic input data. For example:

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(MyTestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void Debit_WithValidAmount_UpdatesBalance_WithDynamicData(double balance, double debit)
{
    // ...method called twice with {12.99, 1.23} and {55.00, 45.00}
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> MyTestData()
{
    // Generator method to create dynamic test data
    yield return new object[] { 12.99, 1.23  };
    yield return new object[] { 55.00, 45.00 };
}
```

Similar question, is it possible to use generator methods with Microsoft's `Native Unit Test` framework to create dynamic input data?

Comment: I suggest you read this i[ssue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290099/parameterizing-a-test-using-cppunit), it might help you.

Comment: Is there a VS feature suggestion for that to vote ? Still needed